# CSS, DIV and H1

Tags: html, css

I'm using a template and the titles are inside a `div`. I want to apply `h1` to the title but it goes bad (the `div` is styled with css, and there is no styling for `h1`)

Normally this is what it is:

```
<div class="content-pagetitle">Title</div>
```

I'm changing to:

```
<div class="content-pagetitle"><h1>Title</h1></div>
```

But it goes bad.

I tryed to use the same styling `content-pagetitle` for `h1`. It didn't worked

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

(It does not become same as content-pagetitle)

Is there a css code that says "do not apply any styling to `h1`"?

Comment: It's really hard to answer this question without seeing the relevant CSS code. I am sure it has something to do with CSS inheritance, but hard to say for sure until you've posted the code.

Comment: Why not using <h1 class="content-pagetitle">Title</h1> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might try removing margins and padding on the `H1`

```
h1 { margin:0; padding:0 }
```

I would encourage you to explore you dom (via firebug or any equivalent) and see which styles are being applied to the `H1`. You may need a more specified selector to apply the aforementioned rules to a particular `h1` element only.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers have default styles that attempt to reasonably display a valid HTML document, even when it has no accompanying css. This generally means that h1 elements will get extra padding, a large font size, bold font-weight, etc.

One way to deal with these is to use a [reset stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). That may be overkill here, so you might just want to use firebug or something to identify the specific styles you want to kill, and override them.

If you're having trouble getting your styles to override, stack more selectors to add more [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a css code to say "do not apply any styling to h1"?

Not as such, no. *But...*

What you could do is specify 'inherit' as the value of the `h1`'s attributes. This is unlikely to work in all situations, though. Assuming:

```
div#content-pagetitle {
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
background-color: inherit; /* background-color would be #fff */
color: inherit; /* color would be #000 */
font-size: inherit; /* font-size would be 2*2em (so 4* the page's base font-size) */
font-weight: inherit; /* font-weight would be bold */
}
```

It might be possible to increase the specificity of the selector, by using:

```
div#content-pagetitle > h1
```

or

```
div#content-pagetitle > h1#element_id_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here is what I would do...
define all your `h` tags as usual, then for the specific style, do something like

```
<h1 class="specialH1"> ... </h1>
```

and in your css

```
h1.specialH1 (
/* style attributes */
)
```

I think thats a clean solution, and gives you full control, whilst not having to alter or reset your default `h` tags.
It also avoids using any selector increasing type black magic witchcraft xD

Anyways... Just my opinion... Hope this helps anybody